# Loading more Instagram comments and likes

Tags: java, comments, instagram, social-likes

Task.
Load more comments and likes.

Description.
I'm using: 
query_hash=f0986789a5c5d17c2400faebf16efd0d for comments
query_hash=e0f59e4a1c8d78d0161873bc2ee7ec44 for likes.

There are 3 variables in a query:
 1. "shortcode". Always the same for my case.
 2. "first". A number of appropriate items.
 3. "after".

PL - Java.

Issue.

Where can I get the initial and following value for "after" variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `after` key in the `variables` dict. Initial value you can specify whatever you want but the maximum number of edges returned per query is `50`.

Answer (score 0):

The "after" is cursor position, initially it is NULL or can be omited and in next request can be obtained for the previous response:

`data.shortcode_media.edge_liked_by.page_info.end_cursor`

A sample:

```
{
    "data": {
        "shortcode_media": {
            "id": "XXX",
            "shortcode": "YYY",
            "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 2029,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": true,
                    "end_cursor": "QVFCSi1hR01ZZExCVk1TZFRfUzluSmJZZGwy..."
                },
            }
        }
    },
    "status": "ok"
}
```